# NGINX proxy_pass returns content-type HTML instead of content-type JAVASCRIPT

Tags: nginx, proxypass, resolve, nginx-upstreams, upstream

I have the following NGINX config

```
events {}

http {
  access_log       /dev/stdout;
  error_log        /dev/stderr;

  resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 valid=5s ipv6=off; # CloudFlare DNS resolver

  upstream myupstream {
    server       xyz.appspot.com:443;
  }

  server {
    server_name            www. mywebsite.com;
    listen                 80;

    set $myupstream "xyz.appspot.com:443";

    location ^~ /mypath/ {
      proxy_pass       https://myupstream/theirpath/;  # <-------- Case A - proxy_pass via UPSTREAM
      proxy_pass       https://$myupstream/theirpath/; # <-------- Case B - proxy_pass via VARIABLE
      proxy_set_header Host "$myupstream";
    }
  }
}

# TEST_URL:                http://www.mywebsite.com/mypath/framework.js
# DESTINATION_URL:         https://xyz.appspot.com:443/theirpath/framework.js
```

The problem occurs in the `proxy_pass` lines

### When I use **Case A** ✅ ...

... proxy_pass via UPSTREAM... the TEST_URL returns correct header `Content-Type: application/javascript` as expected

### When I use **Case B** ❌ ...

... proxy_pass via VARIABLE... the TEST_URL returns incorrect header `Content-Type: text/html`.

This results in faulty rendering by the browser.

---

### How can I ensure "Case B" returns correctly like "Case A" does?

I ensured that the DESTINATION_URL is correctly returning `Content-Type: application/javascript` every time.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?